# Use Ant to tag a build in CVS

Tags: ant, cvs

I'm building off of HEAD, and with each extract from CVS, I want to use Ant to tag at the point that I did the extract, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Think about it "backwards" though and it becomes easy.  First have Ant tag the code in the HEAD.  Then have Ant pull from the tag.

The reason you have to reverse the order is someone could change the HEAD after you pull.  If you tag first, you have a defined point to pull from.